# Files that produce MVC data in DXA

Tags: 2013, dxa

can anyone help me with the important files that are involved to create the MVC application in DXA. we know when we publish the website from tridion content explorer, the content of the website that we publish will be packed in a zip folder and delivered to a folder where the zip file is extracted and then converted to a website to the root folder of our website.

I want to know the files that generate the whole website to the root folder, from the zip file produced by tridion..

Comment: Can you elaborate your question to get the good answers? Also please mention what you are trying to do and what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Your question remains rather vague, maybe it helps if you give us all the details like what zip file produced by tridion (my guess is you downloaded the DXA 1.1 release from the SDL community site, in that case I have updated my answer for you).

Comment: You understood what i am asking for. and your update is a good answer but where can i find the material to understand the dotnet version, so that i can build it in java.

Answer (score 3):

If with files you mean in what class the `BinaryData` folder is used, then you can find references of it in the following locations (in [DXA 1.1 .NET](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet)):

- `Sdl.Web.Common\Configuration\SiteConfiguration.cs` line 31
- `Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs` line 58

If you then take a look at `Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs` you will find the `GetFilePathFromUrl(string, Localization)` method uses it, which in turn is used in:

- `Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs` line 91
- `Sdl.Web.Tridion\Statics\BinaryFileManager.cs` line 184

Not sure if this all is helpful, since your question does not tell me whay you are looking for this. Maybe you should consider editing your question and letting us know what your problem is, so we can provide a more detailed answer.

### Update

The DXA 1.1 release (the zip you mention I assume) currently only supports .NET, there is no released Java version available yet. We do have a pre release in Java, but that is not for the faint hearted. You have to build it yourself and there is little to no documentation to guide you. We expect to release a DXA Java version (documented and tested, equal to our .NET release) in October 2014.

### Update 2

Reading your updated question again, I think you have a wrong expectation of how SDL Tridion and DXA works. SDL Tridion transport packages are zip files, but these do not contain a web application, they could contain pages of a web site (if you use a static publishing model).
DXA is an MVC web application, where we publish content from the CMS to a Content Data Store. The MVC web application will assemble the views upon request and fetch the published content from the Content Data Store, which means your web application must be already installed, you can't publish that itself from SDL Tridion.

Maybe it helps if you read the [DXA documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/sdldxa11), but keep in mind my first update, it currently only supports ASP.NET MVC.

### Update 3

If you are looking for the source code of DXA, you can find that on GitHub as is also explained on our community site https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet

If you want to build it in Java, as mentioned we have its unfinished source code also available on GitHub (in the develop branch) https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/tree/develop

Comment: What if we want to implement MVC application in java?

Comment: @HariKrishnaGaddipati I'm not sure what your question exactly is

Comment: I want the website running in java environment but not a MVC dotnet web application. can i do that? if so what are the files that need to be changed.

Comment: where can i find the material to understand the dotnet version, so that i can build it in java.

Comment: Use the Java version instead, as proposed by Bart?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the answer of question, What is responsible to create DXA web appication (.net)?

It is a power-shell script which is found at `{Install Package}\Web-Application\Install Web-Application.ps1`. While installing the DXA, you need to run that.

Comment: I get the feeling this question is actually about the DXA Java pre release, in which case there currently is no installer, but there is a [readme](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/develop/README.md) describing how to build and run it (i.e build and deploy the war file)

Comment: Good catch @BartKoopman, his comment suggests so.